# Value error converting from float to int in python (very weird problem)

Tags: integer

I am new to python. I am not good at English.
I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5MgV.png) got an error "invalid literal for int() with base 10"
I was converting a float number from float to int and got that error.
I don't know what to do.
plz help.

Comment: Next time, you could try to create a minimal example and put it in the question, not an image. 

See where it says `line 41` in the traceback. The matching source line is `output4 = int(input1)`. input1 is the only variable used. `input1` is only assigned to once at line 4. So you can remove all the code between `input 1 = input( ...` and `output4 = int( ...` to reproduce the problem like `input1 = input('Insert a number you wanna convert'); output4 = int(input1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string, bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix base. Optionally, the literal can be preceded by + or - (with no space in between) and surrounded by whitespace. A base-n literal consists of the digits 0 to n-1, with a to z (or A to Z) having values 10 to 35. The default base is 10. The allowed values are 0 and 2–36. Base-2, -8, and -16 literals can be optionally prefixed with 0b/0B, 0o/0O, or 0x/0X, as with integer literals in code. Base 0 means to interpret exactly as a code literal, so that the actual base is 2, 8, 10, or 16, and so that int('010', 0) is not legal, while int('010') is, as well as int('010', 8).

It is rejecting the decimal point in your input string when you pass it to the builtin `int` function.

```py
num = "1.5"
print(type(num)) # <class 'str'>
print(int(num)) # ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.5'
```

```py
num = "2"
print(type(num)) # <class 'str'>
print(int(num)) #2
```

```py
num = 1.5
print(type(num)) # <class 'float'>
int_num = int(num)
print(type(int_num)) # <class 'int'>
print(int_num) # 1
```

```py
num = "1.5"
float_num = float(num)
print(type(float_num)) # <class 'float'>
print(float_num) # 1.5
int_num = int(float_num)
print(type(int_num)) # <class 'int'>
print(int_num) # 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs from trying to convert a stringed float into an integer.
In order to avoid this error, you must first convert the string into a float, and then convert again to an integer.

An easy solution for your code is to add a float method inside the int method. Simply change line 41 to:

```
output4 = int(float(input1))
```

Comment: your answer was great. because you explained the problem in very short.thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because we try to convert “100.5: to an integer. The value “100.5” is formatted as a string. Python cannot convert a floating-point number in a string to an integer.

We can do this by using the float() and int() statements. The int() function returns an integer. The float() function returns a floating-point representation of a float.

**Solution:**

Replace your line 41 with `output4 = int(float(input1))`